# has_many :through not setting all columns upon creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have users and issues which are joined by a has_many through model called voterships. Users vote on issues. A user can either vote up or down and the join model contains the user_id and the issue_id. However, when I go to create a new vote, only one of the columns gets created. I know i'm doing this wrong. Here are my files:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :users, :through => :associations

  has_many :voterships
  has_many :users, :through => :voterships

  belongs_to :app

  def cast_vote_up!
    voterships.create!(:issue_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

and this is in the votership controller:

```
  def create
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
    #debugger
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:votership][:issue_id])
    @issue.cast_vote_up!
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  end
```

votership model:

```
class Votership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :issue
end
```

and the view with the vote button:

```
<%= form_for(@issue.voterships.build(:issue_id => @issue.id)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :issue_id %>
  <%= f.submit "VoteUp" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide current_user.id to @issue.cast_vote_up! method.

```
def cast_vote_up!(user_id)
  voterships.create!(:issue_id => self.id, :user_id => user_id)
end
```

Would be good to have some kind of validation in Votership model, at least for user_id and issue_id presence.

Comment: great, how do I provide that using the form I have? or do I do that in the issues controller? also, how do i provide what direction to go in? (up or down)

Comment: current_user should be provided in controller. Up or Down in form. I assume that you have 2 forms, if so then just add hidden_filed :up, :value => true, and in second :up, :value => false, check: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag in controller: up = params[:up]